# iOS Passbook Special Characters in Back Fields

Tags: php, ios, passbook

I'm using [PHP-PKPass](https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass) to generate a pass for Passbook on iOS devices. I need to include a copyright symbol (©) on the back in one of the "backFields", but am not having any success.

I've tried copying/pasting an actual copyright symbol (©) into the text, which shows as a missing character (? in a box).

I've also tried using HTML special entity codes, both of which simply show as straight text.

```
&copy;
&#169;
```

I'm thinking that the HTML entities aren't working due to the fact that the pass isn't generated to handle HTML other than scrubbing for hyperlinks and phone numbers via the data detectors (as specified in the [Passbook Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW49)). But I'm still not sure if special characters are even doable as part of the back fields.

Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried `\u00a9`?

Comment: BOOM. @nhahtdh, FTW! That did the trick! If it was an answer, I'd mark it as accepted. Many thanks!

Comment: The `?` in a box is probably due to the encoding that is used to decode the text in your file. I never touched this before so I don't know what kind of encoding is used, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is JSON, you can use `\u00a9` (0xA9 = 169<sub>10</sub>) to specify `©`.

HTML entities are not relevant here.